# I'm trying to print from main function based on exit values from a child function

Tags: c, scanf

I want to print different print statements generated from arithmetic calculations and also from 3 different errors (wrong format, dividing by zero and wrong operator).

The problem I'm dealing with right now is that no matter what the input is, the program prints out "Wrong statement" from exit(50) even if the format is correct...

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int childFunction(char *string);

char input;
char *string = &input;
int status;
int pid;

int main (void)
{
    printf("This program makes simple arithmetics\n");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter an arithmetic statement, e.g., 34 + 132\n");
        input = scanf("%s",&input);

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)   // Error creating child process
        {
            perror("Impossible to fork\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        else if (pid == 0)    // Child process
            childFunction(&input);

        else
        {
            if (pid > 0)  // Parent process
            {
                printf("Created a child to make your operation, waiting\n");
                wait(&status);

                sleep(2);

                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 50)
                printf("Wrong Statement\n\n");

                else if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 100)
                printf("Division by zero\n\n");

                else
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 200)
                    printf("Wrong operator\n\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return (0);
}

int childFunction(char *string)
{
    int n1, n2;
    char op;
    float div = n1/n2;

    printf("I am a child working for my parent\n\n");
    sscanf(string, "%d %c %d", &n1, &op, &n2);

    if ((sscanf(&input,"%d %c %d", &n1, &op, &n2)) != 3)
        exit(50);

    if (op == '/' && n2 == 0)
        exit(100);

    switch (op)
    {
            case '+':
            printf("\n%d %c %d = %d", n1, op, n2, n1+n2);

            case '-':
            printf("\n%d %c %d = %d", n1, op, n2, n1-n2);

            case '/':
            printf("\n%d %c %d = %f", n1, op, n2, div);

            case '*':
            printf("\n%d %c %d = %d", n1, op, n2, n1*n2);

            default:
            exit(200);
    }
    exit(0);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char input;

if ((sscanf(&input,"%d %c %d", &n1, &op, &n2)) != 3)
    exit(50);
```

the first parameter of `sscanf` requires a pointer to a string, not to a single character.